# Postgres select and merge rows

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a table which looks something like this:

```
user_id | key         | scope     | value
--------+-------------+-----------+-------
1       | someSetting | user      | false
1       | someSetting | group     | true
1       | someSetting | company   | false
2       | someSetting | user      | false
2       | someSetting | group     | true
3       | someSetting | user      | false
4       | someSetting | group     | true
```

The settings are in a hierarchy: `company -> group -> user`, with the user overriding the group which in turn overrides the company. When querying by `user_id`, I want to effectively merge the settings by this hierarchy, if it exists. For the above sample, I want to see this as the result:

```
user_id | key         | value
--------+-------------+-------
1       | someSetting | false
2       | someSetting | true
3       | someSetting | false
4       | someSetting | true
```

I am currently doing the merge operation after the rows are retrieved from Postgres, but it would be more efficient if this can be done in the query itself. I looked at aggregate functions, but doesn't look like any of them fit my requirement.

This *seems* simple enough that I'm sure it can be done using Postgres. Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function with a `PARTITION BY` and a pretty cool `ORDER BY`.

**Idea:**

1. Get a `ROW_NUMBER` for every record with the same `user_id` and `ORDER BY` a custom sort order.
2. `SELECT` everything you want from the CTE `a` `WHERE` row number is 1.

**Example:**

```
WITH a AS
(
    SELECT user_id
         , key
         , scope
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id 
                             ORDER BY array_position(array['user','group','company'], scope)) AS rno
    FROM test
)
SELECT user_id
     , key
     , scope
FROM a
WHERE rno = 1;
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v6bqGpiqQF972i6JSSwAF4/1) to show it work.

---

**Bonus:**
If you were to make a function to do this you could even pass in other arrays for setting a custom sort order.

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat query! Didn't know about `array_position`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to change your scope settings from separate rows to separate columns, so your recordset looks like this (note I'm using 0 for false and 1 for true):

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
| user_id |     key     | user_setting | group_setting | company_setting |
+---------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
|       1 | someSetting | 0            | 1             | 0               |
|       2 | someSetting | 0            | 1             | NULL            |
|       3 | someSetting | 0            | NULL          | NULL            |
|       4 | someSetting | NULL         | 1             | NULL            |
+---------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

To do this, you have a few options. Here's one of them, using conditional aggregation. Basically, you group by `user_id` and `key`, then combine an aggregate function (it can be either `MIN` or `MAX`) with a `CASE` statement:

```
WITH 
    settings_pivot AS
    (
        SELECT
            [user_id],
            [key],
            MIN(CASE WHEN [scope] = 'user' THEN [value] ELSE NULL END) AS user_setting,
            MIN(CASE WHEN [scope] = 'group' THEN [value] ELSE NULL END) AS group_setting,
            MIN(CASE WHEN [scope] = 'company' THEN [value] ELSE NULL END) AS company_setting
        FROM settings
        GROUP BY
            [user_id],
            [key]
    )
SELECT 
    [user_id], 
    [key], 
    COALESCE(user_setting, group_setting, company_setting) AS derived_setting
FROM settings_pivot
```

If you just `SELECT *` from the settings_pivot CTE, you'll get the pivoted data I have at the beginning. Using `COALESCE`, however, you give precedence as you indicate.

**Note**: I'm using SQL Server, since Postgres on my machine doesn't want to boot up. So you'll have to replace the square braces with double quotes: `"user_id"` instead of `[user_id]`.